# How do you fix a program from freezing when you move the window in SDL2?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-8, window, sdl-2

I'm making a small game with a friend and one problem is that when you drag the window around, it freezes and the program completely stops until you let go. I searched for a simple solution but I only found out that it happens with everything. Also, it screws up the delta time since it acts like a really long frame. Is there any way to either simply have the program continue running while you move it or if that's too complicated, fix the delta time? Thanks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application is most likely "freezing" because it has a WinMain loop similar to this:

```
while (true) 
{
    if(PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
       TickGame();
    }
}
```

So instead of ticking it is processing the [WM_MOVE message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632631(v=vs.85).aspx) .  One simple work around would be just to call your games tick function within the move message, or perhaps it makes sense to pause the game when you get the first move message and unpause it if you haven't gotten one for a second or two.  That is, are people really going to be dragging the window WHILE playing, unlikely.

To answer your second question, typically games (physics engines especially) will use a fixed time step to stabilize the simulation, read more about fixed time step [here](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/).

Comment: Thanks! I think that the message would be event.window.event if it equals SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MOVED. Then if I get that message I could either pause the game or nullify the delta time. I could even run the update function but that might not work as well and it's not like people will pay it while they nice it, as you said.

Comment: Could you just ignore the window move message, I don't see what you would do with this information (except may be make everything fall over in the game if it is moved to fast).