# How to stop freezing rendering video while moving or resizing sdl window?

Tags: windows, resize, sdl, move, freeze

The problem is that video rendering pauses while I am moving windows with mouse drag and works fine after I release the mouse.
After long time of googling I found the reason but I don't know how to fix it.
the reason was that default window event are being processed before sdl events work. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29554656/1021959) question but couldn't understand.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you fix a program from freezing when you move the window in SDL2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552658/how-do-you-fix-a-program-from-freezing-when-you-move-the-window-in-sdl2)